# Autoindex cuts off end of directory path; workaround needed

Tags: nginx, alias, shared-hosting

I'm trying to set up a sort of shared hosting with nginx where each user has a `public_html` directory. Requests to `/~username` are aliased to `/home/domain-users/username/public_html`. Problem is, I also want autoindexing enabled. With the config below added into a server block, requests to specific files like `/~username/test.txt` work fine; they are aliased to `/home/domain-users/username/public_html/test.txt`. However, when trying to request `/~username` or `~/username/`, I get a 404 and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` reveals that autoindex is for some reason attempting to list files in `/home/domain-users/username/public_htm` (note the missing "l": the path is truncated.)

Since being able to access `/~username` without a trailing slash as a directory is not vital, I tried removing `$public_html_path/` from the `try_files` directive. Then, even when requesting `/~username/`, autoindex is not called. Perhaps a literal trailing slash is required in `try_files` for autoindex to function.

```
# For requests to "/~username" without a trailing slash
set $public_html_path "";
# Lazy quantifier at the end allows processing requests to "~/username". We add the trailing slash later in try_files
location ~ ^\/\~(?<user_home_folder>[^\\n\/]+)(?<public_html_path>\/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/domain-users/$user_home_folder/public_html;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $public_html_path $public_html_path/ =404;
}
```

My research has yielded scant results, the closest being [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921479/nginx-alias-ignores-last-letter). Since this appears to be a bug in NGINX that's unlikely to be fixed (the last comment was well over a year ago) I'm looking for a workaround. Using the `root` directive instead of `alias` would be perfect, except then autoindex removes the critical `/~username/` part of the URI, thinking that the files it lists are in the web root since, in a way, they are. Even hacky workarounds will be very much appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `alias` with a regular expression `location`, you need to reconstruct the entire pathname in the `alias` value. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

```
location ~ ^/~(?<user_home_folder>[^/]+)(?<public_html_path>/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/domain-users/$user_home_folder/public_html$public_html_path;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Using `try_files` and `alias` together can cause complications due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). But, the default behaviour is virtually identical to the `try_files` statement in your question.

Comment: Amazing! I feel kinda dumb now...